# Quoting issue while echoing a html part from php to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

In my php file I am echoing back an html response to my jQuery function.
Due some wrong quoting that I am applying data is no being passed through onclick event

```
echo "  <div class='img-x' id='img-x-".$newdata['id']."' ><span onclick='test('".$newdata['id']."','".$newdata['image_path']."');'  class='icon-remove'></span></div>  <img src='http://localhost/corridor/uploads/".$actual_image_name."'  class='img_prvw' id='img-x-".$newdata['id']."' />";
```

in html it shows like this

```
<span onclick="test(" 164','13906347455190.jpg');' class="icon-remove"></span>
```

Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You mean, apart from expecting the onclick handler to work after you add the HTML to the dom?

Comment: yeah the code I gave there is a view form chrome inspect element ...

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the `quotes` properly.

```
echo "<div class='img-x' id='img-x-".$newdata['id']."'><span onclick=\"test('".$newdata['id']."','".$newdata['image_path']."');\" class='icon-remove'></span></div>  <img src='http://localhost/corridor/uploads/".$actual_image_name."'  class='img_prvw' id='img-x-".$newdata['id']."' />";
                                                                     ^
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are ajaxing this in:

```
echo <<< _html
<div class="img-x" id="img-x-$newdata['id']">
  <span data-id="$newdata['id']" data-imagepath="$newdata['image_path']" 
    class="icon-remove"></span>
</div>
<img src="http://localhost/corridor/uploads/$actual_image_name" 
   class="img_prvw" id="img-x-$newdata['id']" />
_html;
```

and in the succes:

```
success: function() { 
  $("#someContainer").html(data);
  $("#someContainer .icon-remove").on("click",function() {
    test($(this).data("id"),$(this).data("imagepath"));
  });
}
```

If no ajax then

```
echo <<< _html
<div class="img-x" id="img-x-$newdata['id']">
  <span onclick="test('$newdata['id']','$newdata['image_path'].')" 
  class="icon-remove"></span>
</div>
<img src="http://localhost/corridor/uploads/$actual_image_name" 
  class="img_prvw" id="img-x-$newdata['id']" />
_html;
```